# Run GDB repeatedly on an executable file (and halt on crashes/errors)

Tags: c++, gdb

I am trying to figure out a way to run an executable with GDB **repeatedly** and preferably halt on errors.

I could not find a way to do this in the manual!

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I tried (in Bash):

```
while true ; do gdb -ex run a.out -ex quit ; done ;
```

Unfortunately, this turned out to be rather tricky to kill off, but it did automate running, and when the program crashed (I tested with an old program that causes a SIGABRT), gdb asks "The program is running.  Exit anyway? (y or n)", so just hit n.

Comment: Just tried this. To kill it just hit `ctrl-Z` and then `kill %[job number]`. You can use `jobs` to check the job number.

Comment: while true ; do gdb -ex run a.out -ex quit ; sleep 0.2; done ;

Answer (score 9):

I ran into this same problem, and came up with what I think is a fairly nice way of stopping the infinite loop that BoBTFish suggested.

Instead of looping `while true`, you can use the existence of a dummy file to control the loop, e.g:

```
touch loopfile; while [ -f loopfile ] ; do gdb -ex run a.out -ex quit ; done ;
```

When you want to stop your infinite debugging session, you can either open a new terminal in the same directory and `rm loopfile`, or you can exit from the same terminal by interrupting with `control-c` and then deleting `loopfile` from within `gdb`:

```
^CQuit
A debugging session is active.

    Inferior 1 [process 11136] will be killed.

Quit anyway? (y or n) n
Not confirmed.
(gdb) shell rm loopfile 
(gdb) quit
A debugging session is active.

    Inferior 1 [process 11136] will be killed.

Quit anyway? (y or n) y
```

Hopefully this is useful to someone in the future, it seems like a nice (if hackish) way of debugging intermittent problems.

Answer (score 4):

## Loop + LD path + command line args example

```
for i in {0..99}; do LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/some/path/to/libs gdb -ex 'set args arg1 arg2 arg3' -ex run ./execName -ex quit ; done
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a shell script to run `gdb` repedatedly, and use the `--batch -x <cmdfile>` options to `gdb` to specify a command file that simply has the word `run` to run the program. So something like this:

```
$ echo run > cmdfile ; while gdb --batch -x cmdfile myprogram ; do : ; done
```

Answer (score 1):

One simple way consist in placing one breakpoint at the end of your code, and configure the breakpoint commands to run the program again.
For example, if your program always passes through the last main line (assuming no abrupt exit) then you can:

```
(gdb) b <last line of main here>
(gdb) commands
> run [command line args]
> end
```

You may just CTRL-C to stop the execution. Of course GDB will stop execution if it find a segmentation fault or another breakpoint, allowing you to catch errors.

For most complex cases you can use your imagination to find a good place for breakpoints. For example you may set the bp on the exit() function.